# Are Campagnolo 11 speed ESP and 11 speed XPSS chainrings compatible

Tags: chainring, campagnolo

I need to replace some 11 speed ESP chainrings (not to be confused with EPS, their e-shifting tech). I am only finding 11 speed XPSS chainrings.

Campagnolo calls XPSS:

> X.P.S.S.™ Extreme Performance Shifting System

There is very little info about ESP Actuation System on the internet (hard enough to force search engines to *not* return EPS results). All the XPSS info I can find refers to their newer 12 speed lineup.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What did you ever find out. I need an xpss and can only find esp..

Comment: @Jsees as long as you fit a matching pair (either ESP or XPSS) shifting will be correct.

Comment: Research shows XPSS is an optimized tooth profile on the chainrings they have introduced 2010 or 2011 and I would guess by the less dramatic nomenclature (and some older 11-speed cranks found in various online stores listing this "feature"), ESP was the predecessor. I'm no Campy expert but would guess as long as other factors (like BCD) are the same, you just get an upgraded shifting experience and XPSS ones are easier to get than the older ones...